# Line chart in Power BI not showing all of my data?

Tags: powerbi, linechart

I have a line chart in Power BI that tracks different metrics over time. The X axis is week number (e.g. 1st week of the year is 1 and so on). A slicer is used to select which weeks to look at.

However, no matter what's selected on the slicer the chart only goes up to week 12:

[image: power bi line chart]

I've confirmed that the table this chart gets data from is fully populated up to week 14. If I add a card to the report holding any of the metrics used in the chart, they show data for weeks 13 & 14.

If I go into the x axis settings and set the end of the axis to 14 the axis goes up to 14 but the chart still shows no data beyond week 12.

Does anyone know what the problem might be please?

If it helps, the x axis is set to type = continuous and scale type = linear.

Comment: If you [hover on the filter icon for the visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-report-filter) do you see any unexpected filters?

Comment: @AlexisOlson: No, there are no filters that would explain why only data for these weeks is appearing.